# DotNetNuke Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, dotnetnuke

I'm new to DOTNETNUKE and facing little problem when adding a crystal report to a module. I'm using VS 2008 Crystal Reports extension.
I created a module to display a crystal report, but in the code behind of the user control the Crystal Report class is not visible

```
CrystalReport2 rpt=new CrystalReport2()
rpt.SetDataSource(dt)
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt
```

CrystalReport2 is not identified. But CrystalReportViewer1 is displaying the report format correctly in the design mode. How do I create crystal report object?
Please Help,

Thank you,

kushira.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the imports/using statement to the code behind for the CR references?

Comment: Thanks. But I have already tried it but no use. Anyhow I completed this by developing the module by not using the template.